# Accessing variables from different functions

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two variables `let bonus` and `let itemlevel2` which I want to use in the function `getResponse`.
The `itemlevel2` variable is the current chosen value of a slider.

At the moment I can only use the `itemlevel2` variable in the getResponse function, but I can´t access the `bonus` variable.

How can I use both variables in the getResponse function correctly?

```
jQuery(function ($) {

    $(function () {   
        $("#slider-vertical").slider({
            orientation: "horizontal",
            range: "min",
            min: 0,
            slide: function (event, ui) {
                $("#amount").val(ui.value);
            },
        });

        getResponse(0);
        $('ul#menu li').click(function () {
            let bonus = $(this).attr("value");
            getResponse(bonus);
        });

        $('#slider-vertical').on('slide', function (event, ui) {
            let itemlevel2 = $("#slider-vertical").slider("value");
            getResponse(itemlevel2);
        });

    });

    function getResponse(itemlevel2, bonus) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            cache: "true",
            url: "itemscript.php",
            data: {
                "bonus": bonus,
                "itemlevel": itemlevel2
            },
            success: function (data) {
                $('.item-content').html('<div class="tooltipitem-site"><div class="ui-tooltip-site">' + data + '</div></div>');

            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Your `getResponse` function expects *two* arguments (`itemlevel2` and `bonus`) but you are always calling it passing just the first one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to achieve this would be to invert the dependency so that the `getResponse()` function is responsible for retrieving the information it needs from the DOM.

This way you avoid the 'async' issue of the `bonus` and `itemlevel2` values being set at different times, and also the need for any global variables. Try this:

```js
jQuery($ => {
  $("#slider-vertical").slider({
    orientation: "horizontal",
    range: "min",
    min: 0,
    slide: function(event, ui) {
      $("#amount").val(ui.value);
    },
  });

  getResponse(0);
  
  let $li = $('ul#menu li').on('click', function() {
    // set a class on the clicked element to be able to read its properties later
    $li.removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
    getResponse();
  });

  $('#slider-vertical').on('slide', getResponse);
});

function getResponse() {
  let bonus = $('ul#menu li.active').attr('value');
  let itemlevel2 = $("#slider-vertical").slider("value");

  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    cache: "true",
    url: "itemscript.php",
    data: {
      "bonus": bonus,
      "itemlevel": itemlevel2
    },
    success: function(data) {
      $('.item-content').html('<div class="tooltipitem-site"><div class="ui-tooltip-site">' + data + '</div></div>');
    }
  });
}
```

As a side note, your code implies that the `li` has a `value` attribute which is not valid HTML. If you want to store custom metadata on an element in the DOM use `data` attributes instead, eg. `data-value`.